# How do I rename or replace signals using asammdf?

Tags: python, mdf

I have mdf files that have the names of some channels in a different language. I want to rename those channels in English. I've tried to do so, but there doesn't seem to be any renaming function in the documentation. Another option could be to copy the signal with a separate name, but that creates a new group with that new signal inside. The group names are not consistent throughout these files so I can't just send each new channel to the correct group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no dedicated function for this, but you can use this snippet to change the names and save the file:

```py
from asammdf import MDF

mdf = MDF(filename)
for group in mdf.groups:
    for channel in group.channels:
        channel.name = translation_function(channel.name)
mdf.save("translated.mf4")
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. Unfortunately, I am getting the error <AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'channels'>. When I look in a group using <mdf.groups>, there is a channels Key.

Comment: You are using a version 4.x.y. You should update to asammdf 5.1.1